# How do I make a VSCode Extension wait on a webview panel being closed and disposed of?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions

I have moved away from using the VSCode `showInputBox` as I have had too many users complain that they are being prompted multiple times for different information and only when all the information has been provided can the input be reconciled and fully validated. If they make a mistake then they have to start over and it is quite painful.
However, the "advantage" of the VSCode `showInputBox` is that the user cannot proceed with other aspects of the extension till he has completed the input and the await of the showinputBox has been resolved..

Using Webview in conjunction with the VSCode `webview-ui-toolkit` is cleaner in that all the input fields can be presented in one panel and then validated etc.

The problem that I am having is that I do not want the user to be able to click elsewhere in this extension till he has completed this user input in the webview panel and the panel disposed of, as other areas of the extension are dependent upon this completed input.

It seems a basic issue, but I have found no documentation that helps on how to make the extension wait on the webview completion and disposal.

Comment: the webview has a callback that notifies it being closed/disposed, ignore all commands when the webview is visible

Comment: Yes, it does, but that tells you when it has been disposed. 
I want the Extension to wait till it has been disposed. 
I cannot stop the user from leaving the webview panel open and him going to the Treeview etc and continuing to select whatever he wants in the meantime.

To have to go check for whether a webview is visible would be really kludgy and involve having to check in hundreds of locations.

Comment: then create a WebviewView, make the form a panel of the view and the Tree another, but you have to implement the tree yourself. find a web toolkit with a tree widget

Comment: That is not going to happen, this is production code and it would effectively be a rewrite. 

I am struggling to believe that VSCode does not provide a built in means to wait on a webview.   I will have to continue to dig.

Comment: why should VSC be able to wait for some asynchronous part of the application, the whole app is async, what you want is a modal dialog, or some block tag that contains your form that is on top of all the GUI of VSC, AFAIK there is none in VSC API

Comment: In exactly the same manner that VSCode's ShowInputBox allows the code to wait for that to be completed

VSCode provides a notification of the webview being disposed, then there should equally be a means to allow the extension to wait on that notification.   The extension has dependencies upon receiving that user input.